# Ajax fails over a complex string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Im trying to send with ajax the following string to a spring MVC controller :

(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$

I get error 400 bad request (it not leaving the client).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: try using escape or encodeURI functions to convert that.

Comment: Please post the full request and the handler method.

Answer (score 0):

using escape("(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.\d)(?=.[!@#$%^&]+)(?![.\n])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[a-z]).$") in my ajax solved my problem